# expand frequency table in r

Tags: r, frequency, cumulative-frequency

Hi everyone I am struggling with something that I think should be easy.

I have a dataset that looks as follows

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Count
 a    b    c     d    10
 z    a    c     f    3
```

I just need a function that replicates the rows based on the count. So I would end up with a new data frame or data table that would have 13 rows.

I am trying to use the `rep()` function to do this, but it isn't working.

```
dat <- read.table(text="Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Count
 a    b    c     d    10
 z    a    c     f    3", header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 4):

Something like this is standard:

```
dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), dat[["Count"]]), ]

##     Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Count
## 1      a    b    c    d    10
## 1.1    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.2    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.3    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.4    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.5    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.6    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.7    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.8    a    b    c    d    10
## 1.9    a    b    c    d    10
## 2      z    a    c    f     3
## 2.1    z    a    c    f     3
## 2.2    z    a    c    f     3
```

Comment: @blast00 - you've got an `NA` in one of the rows I'm guessing.